# Flume Subdirectory

Tags: flume, flume-ng

How to make Flume Spooling Directory Source work with the Sub Directories of a folder too.
My source folder have several other folders too, I want my flume agent to look into these sub directories too for a file to dump it into sink.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The Spooling Directory won't check any of subdirectories, unless you explicitly configure it to check those subdirectories, eg:

```
a1.channels = ch-1
a1.sources = src-1 src-sub-1 src-sub-2

a1.sources.src-1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src-sub-1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src-sub-2.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src-1.channels = ch-1
a1.sources.src-sub-2.channels = ch-1
a1.sources.src-sub-1.channels = ch-1
a1.sources.src-1.spoolDir = /var/log/apache/flumeSpool
a1.sources.src-sub-1.spoolDir = /var/log/apache/flumeSpool/subdir
a1.sources.src-sub-2.spoolDir = /var/log/apache/flumeSpool/secondSubdir
```

Answer (score 0):

In the currently release version of Flume (1.6.0) there isn't a way to do so however there is an issue being worked on to do this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-1899

There is a patch available in the issue - this may/may not help you depending on whether you're able to build a custom Flume deployable.

Answer (score 0):

a1.sources.src-1.recursiveDirectorySearch=true 
It will check all sub-directories present in directory.